# TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances

Tags: python

```
# This is recipe conversion program
import fractions
from fractions import *

def getfile():
    filename = input("Enter file name: ")
    num_attempts = 1
    inputfile_limit = False
    while not inputfile_limit and num_attempts < 3:
        try:
            readFile = open(filename, 'r')
            inputfile_limit = True
        except IOError:
            print("File Open Error")
            num_attempts += 1
            filename = input("Enter file name: ")

    if num_attempts == 3:
        raise IOError('Exceed the number of file open attempt')
    return filename, readFile


def delete_digit(text):
    '''This function to delete all the digit of the original text'''
    k = 0
    if k < len(text) and text[k].isdigit() or text[k] == (' ', '/'):
        k += 1
    return text[k, len(text)]


def scanAsFractor(line):
    '''Scan all the input file including digits, fraction and return the fracitons object'''
    Scan_stop = False
    get_fraction = Fraction(0, 1)
    while not Scan_stop:
        k = 0
        while k < len(line) and line[k].isdigit():
            k += 1
        numerator = line[0:k]
        if k < len(line) and line[k] == '/':
            k += 1
            flash = k
            while k < len(line) and line[k].isdigit():
                k += 1
            denominator = line[flash:k]
        else:
            denominator = 1
        get_fraction = get_fraction + Fraction(numerator, denominator)
        if k == len(line):
            Scan_stop = True
        else:
            line = line[k:len(line)].strip()
            if not line[0].isdigit():
                Scan_stop = True
    return get_fraction


def convertline(line, factor):
    """If line begins with a digit, returns line with the value multiplied by factor. Otherwise, returns line unaterd"""
    global conv_line
    if line[0].isdigit():
        blank_char = ''
        frac_result = scanAsFractor(line) * factor
        if frac_result.getDenominator() == 1:
            frac_result = frac_result.getNumerator()
        conv_line = str(frac_result) + blank_char + delete_digit(line)
    else:
        conv_line = line
    return conv_line


# Main
# get file name and open file
file_name, input_filename = getfile()

# Get conversion factor
conv_factor = input("Enter the conversion factor: ")
conv_factor = scanAsFractor(conv_factor)

# Open output file name
output_file_name = "conv_" + file_name
output_file = open(output_file_name, 'w')

# Covert recipe
empty_str = ''
recipe_line = input_filename.readline()

while recipe_line != empty_str:
    recipe_line = convertline(recipe_line, conv_factor)
    output_file.write(recipe_line)
    recipe_line = input_filename.readline()


#close file
input_filename.close()
output_file.close()
```

this is the recipe conversion program that copies the input file's content has the format:
Chocolate Chip Cookie Recipe.
9/2 cups of all-purpose flour.
2 teaspoon baking soda.
2 cups butter, softened.
3/2 cups packed brown sugar.
1/2 white sugar.
1/2 white sugar.
2 packages of instant vanilla pudding mix.
4 eggs.

and the output should be:
Enter file name:
Enter the conversion factor: 2
Converted recipe in file:

the output of the converted recipe file is as below:
Chocolate Chip Cookie Recipe.
9 cups of all-purpose flour.
4 teaspoon baking soda.
4 cups butter, softened.
3 cups packed brown sugar.
1 white sugar.
1 white sugar.
4 packages of instant vanilla pudding mix.
8 eggs.

but I got this error, can you help me fix my code?

```
Enter file name: chocchipcookie.txt
Enter the conversion factor: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Downloads/CS/object-oriented programming/A Recipe Conversion Program/recipe conversion program.py", line 78, in <module>
    conv_factor = scanAsFractor(conv_factor)
  File "/Users/mac/Downloads/CS/object-oriented programming/A Recipe Conversion Program/recipe conversion program.py", line 48, in scanAsFractor
    get_fraction = get_fraction + Fraction(numerator, denominator)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/fractions.py", line 174, in __new__
    raise TypeError("both arguments should be "
TypeError: both arguments should be Rational instances
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The `numerator` (always) and `denominator` (sometimes) you're passing to `Fraction` are still `str` objects, you haven't parsed them to `int`s, just sliced out sub-`str`s. Change:

```
get_fraction = get_fraction + Fraction(numerator, denominator)
```

to:

```
get_fraction = get_fraction + Fraction(int(numerator), int(denominator))
# or the less repetitive:
get_fraction += Fraction(int(numerator), int(denominator))
```

to coerce to `int` before construction. Alternatively, coerce at time of extraction (to make the errors appear as soon as possible), e.g.:

```
numerator = int(line[:k])  # No need for explicit 0; that's the default slice start
```

and:

```
denominator = int(line[flash:k])
```